# Copy and Paste Excel Formatted Data within sheet without formulla

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to copy my data which i have carefully formatted and designed , and paste it on another location of same worksheet but i want to pasted data to **retain formatting** and **formula must be removed only value remain** in their place.

what could be workaround to do the above mentioned task in **excel 2013/2010** ?

Comment: What do you mean by formatting? Police, number of decimals and such alike?

Comment: yes something like that , coloring , data shape etc

Comment: Maybe we schould migrate this question to superuser.com.

Comment: yes i think that's good idea @DirkHorsten

Comment: why not simply copy the source and at the upper left cell of destination right click -> paste special -> (under paste values) values & source formatting?

Comment: If that option is present, indeed. (I did not have Excel at hand when I answeren)

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps

1. copy formatting with one of the following methods

   - select the source and press the bruch icon, then click the left upper corner of the destination
   - simply copy the source onto the destination, knowing that you will overwrite the formulas in the next step.
     z. copy values
   - select the source again and press the copy item (or faster: press [CTRL]-C), then right- click the left upper corner of the destination and select the numbers icon.
   - in older versoins of excel, this is an ootion in `edit` _ `copy special`